# How to save an excel file to a specific location C#?

Tags: c#

This is a Windows Form Application using .NET framework which saves records into a MS Database. Also has the option to export database as an excel file.

This is my 'Create excel file' button click function:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from [dbo].[Table]";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet("New_DataSet");
        ds.Locale = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        da.Fill(dt);
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook("MyExcelFile.xls",ds);

        MessageBox.Show("Archivo excel generado correctamente.");

        con.Close();
    }
```

Using my published version of the app, noticed that the excel file is created in the "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\ZDTK7LMQ.YEZ\V0BOPT21.N23" my default.

Id' like to change saving location. Any clues?

PD: The excel library I'm using is "ExcelLibrary".

```
using ExcelLibrary.CompoundDocumentFormat;
using ExcelLibrary.SpreadSheet;
using ExcelLibrary.BinaryDrawingFormat;
using ExcelLibrary.BinaryFileFormat;
```

Comment: Just simply try to specify a full path instead of a relativ path (only name) - so try this: `ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook("C:\\Test\\MyExcelFile.xls",ds);` - if you want to let the user decide where he wants to save the file use a `SaveFileDialog` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

What if you try add \ one slash or  two slashes \ \ in front of filename and see if that makes a difference: "\MyExcelFile.xls" or "\ \ MyExcelFile.xls". Also, you may want to take out the file name and construct the file name and path as a string then add string to the call like so:

```
var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "desired_dir_name"); // bin, etc
string myFileNameAndPath = path + "\\" + "MyExcelFile.xls";
ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook(myFileNameAndPath ,ds);
```

Run debugger through above to see what paths are getting set and modify location to your needs.